# Is there more 'pythonic' way to do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example, we need to write a function that finds the first '@' in the string and return the substring made of 0 or more alphabetic chars following the @, so 'xx@abc$$' returns 'abc'. If no @ is present, return the empty string.

I solved it like that but is there a more pythonic way to do that?

```
def func(s):
    at = s.find('@')
    if at == -1:
        return ''
    end = at + 1
    while end < len(s) and s[end].isalpha():
        end += 1
    return s[at+1:end]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex`:

```
import re
def func(s):
    r = re.search(r'@([A-Za-z]+)', s)
    return r.group(1) if r else ""
print(func('xx@abc$$')) # abc
```

This pattern also works:

```
r = re.search(r'@(\w+)', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex, using the pattern `r'@([A-Za-z]+)'` which matches a leading `@` followed by one of more alphabets

```
import re

def func(s):

    pattern = r'@([A-Za-z]+)'
    match = re.search(pattern, s)

    #Return match if found else return empty string
    return match.group(1) if match else ''

print(func('xx@abc$$'))
print(func('xx@abc$$'))
print(func('xx@ab12$$'))
print(func('xxabc$$'))
```

The output will be

```
abc
abc
ab
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def func(s):
    # find the @ index
    start_idx = s.find("@")
    # return early if not there
    if start_idx == -1:
        return ""
    # return a string which to it is added the letters that specify criteria
    return "".join([letter for letter in s[start_idx:] if letter.isalpha()])
```

This function will return ALL the characters past the "@" and that are alphanumeric, you didn't specify if you wanted only up to the first non character.